# compare string from variable in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, compare

I have tried all possible things to compare strings in Objective-C.

compare:
isEqualToString:

It works perfect when I do

```
if ([string1 compare:@"sometext"])
{ 
 //dostuff 
}
```

But if I am to use a variable like string2 it fails all the time.

```
if ([string1 compare:string2])
```

I also tried

```
if ([string1 compare:(@"%@", string2)])
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Content of the both strings are md5 checksums like:

```
NSString *string1 = "eb121296f0ed90be93578e50bedb27e3"
NSString *string2 = "eb121296f0ed90be93578e50bedb27e3"
```

I tried all these methods with isEqualToString: as well, without any results...

Is it me or is obj-c driving me crazy?
Thanks in advance,
Wouter

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, maybe I'm misreading, but are you trying to get the order of the strings, or just see if they are the same string. If you're just testing for equality try this.

*Edited after the comments*

Since you are creating the string from an NSData type try this.

```
NSString *string2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

if ([string1 isEqualToString:string2]) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: That's the whole problem. He won't take string2 as valid. I have to type @"content_of_string2", but I really need the variable instead.

Comment: Are the strings valid? Your code says they are checksums "like" but if they are defined that way they are missing the "@". How exactly are you defining them otherwise?

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed the @ in the example. For real they are defined like this : NSString *checkFromS3 = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Etag"]; and NSString *chcksum = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", checksumData]; where checksumData comes from the local file. I NSLogged them both and they are the same

Comment: What is the type of checksumData?

Comment: I use NSData because it comes from my openssl md5 checker

Comment: I found the problem... checkFromS3 is coming from another thread... so there was no problem with the comparasion. Thanks for your effort anyways!

Answer (score 2):

you need to write

```
if ([string1 compare:string2] == NSOrderedSame )
```

Comment: And remember that NSOrderedSame is 0, so checking the result of `-compare` as a boolean will generally give you the opposite of what you think it would.